# React js Context

Tags: reactjs

Estoy intentando guardar los productos de mi carrito con un context, pero cada vez que le doy al boton de agregar me tira el siguiente error:

> TypeError: addItem is not a function

El codigo es el siguiente

```
 import React, { useContext, useState, createContext } from "react";
    
    const CartContext = createContext();
    
    const useCartContext = () => useContext(CartContext);
    
    export const CartProvider = ({ children }) => {
      const [productos, setProductos] = useState([]);
    
      const addItem = ({
        title,
        volumes,
        start_date,
        end_date,
        image_url,
        score,
        mal_id,
      }) => {
        setProductos([
          ...productos,
          { title, volumes, start_date, end_date, image_url, score, mal_id },
        ]);
      };
    
      return (
        <CartContext.Provider value={{ addItem }}>{children}</CartContext.Provider>
      );
    };
    export default useCartContext;



    const ItemDetailContainer = () => {
      const [mangasId, setMangas] = useState([]);
    
      //Context
      const { productos, addItem } = useCartContext;
    
      const { id } = useParams();
    
      function onAdd(cantidad) {
        addItem({
          title: mangasId.title,
        });
      }
```

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: Hay que verificar si `CartProvider` esta envolviendo a la app. saludos

Comment: @g.4 si, lo tengo en el app <CartProvider> mis rutas </CartProvider>

https://i.imgur.com/3vGw5xC.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya se confirmó que el `provider CartProvider` esta envolviendo a la `app`, también se asume que se esta importando el método del contexto `useCartContext`.

Se pueden ver dos detalles, los cuales probablemente esten causando el problema que describes.

#### Invocar a useCartContext

Aquí, se debe invocar a `useCartContext`:

```
 //Context
      const { productos, addItem } = useCartContext;
```

Es decir, así:

```
//Context
      const { productos, addItem } = useCartContext();
```

#### Verificar los valores que proporciona el contexto

En el código se destructuran 2 valores:

```
const { productos, addItem } = useCartContext();
```

Pero `productos` no parece estar listado en los valores del context:

```
return (
        <CartContext.Provider value={{ addItem }}>{children}</CartContext.Provider>
      );
```

En este caso `addItem` quedó destructurada, pero en la variable `productos`(la destructuración se basa en indices ); por lo tanto, al tratar de invocar a `addItem`, también se tendrá el mensaje de error:

> TypeError: addItem is not a function

Pues no hay nada en la segunda posición de la destructuración. Debería quedar así:

```
const {addItem } = useCartContext();
```

Ahora bien, si se necesita pasar `productos` desde el contexto, se debe listar en los valores de provider:

```
 <CartContext.Provider value={{ productos, addItem }}>{children}</CartContext.Provider>
```

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.

Comment: era eso muchas gracias!